# How to import actors of ray in other modules?

Tags: python, module, parallel-processing, ray

I'm attempting parallel processing at `main.ipynb`, which imports actors of ray in another module.

It works well when putting `main.ipynb` and class decorated with actors together in one file.

However, there is an error when importing a module defined as an actor to `main.ipynb`.

**System information**

ray version : 1.9.1

python version : 3.7.9

IDE : Jupyter Notebook

**When it's one file**

```
import ray

@ray.remote
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
     
    def process(self):
        print('hello world!')
```

```
people = Person.remote()
people
```

> Actor(Person, 801ec78d595d5cf623ae97b001000000)

```
people.process.remote()
```

> ObjectRef(63964fa4841d4a2e801ec78d595d5cf623ae97b00100000001000000)
> pid=28900) hello world !

```
ray.get(people.process.remote())
```

> pid=28900) hello world !

**When importing from module**

```
#environment.ipynb

import ray

@ray.remote
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self):
        print('hello world!')
```

```
#main.ipynb

import psutil
import import_ipynb
import ray

num_logical_cpus = psutil.cpu_count()
ray.init(num_cpus= num_logical_cpus, ignore_reinit_error=True)
from environment import Person
```

```
people = Person.remote()
```

```
people
```

> Actor(Person, f03935b5166eb8cd4c5f861a01000000)

```
people.process.remote()
```

> ObjectRef(63964fa4841d4a2ef03935b5166eb8cd4c5f861a0100000001000000)

```
ray.get(people.process.remote())
#print(ray.get(people.process.remote()))
#ray.shutdown()
```

> Infinite execution

or

> None

or

```
2021-12-30 21:12:40,346 WARNING worker.py:1245 -- The node with node id: 0d59cda378c20fe9621423e69fdff2a03b9645804d20b8b60cd3fc9c and ip: 127.0.0.1 has been marked dead because the detector has missed too many heartbeats from it. This can happen when a raylet crashes unexpectedly or has lagging heartbeats.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RayActorError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4c29bf88b289> in <module>
----> 1 ray.get(people.process.remote())
      2 #print(ray.get(people.process.remote()))
      3 #ray.shutdown(enter code here`)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ray\_private\client_mode_hook.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    103             if func.__name__ != "init" or is_client_mode_enabled_by_default:
    104                 return getattr(ray, func.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
--> 105         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    106 
    107     return wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ray\worker.py in get(object_refs, timeout)
   1713                     raise value.as_instanceof_cause()
   1714                 else:
-> 1715                     raise value
   1716 
   1717         if is_individual_id:

RayActorError: The actor died unexpectedly before finishing this task.
```

I can't understand why the results change from time to time.